# Animation has no reference

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-physics, game-development, animator

guys when i'm starting game everything's fine but when am trying to move my game stopping and causing errors

> animation footL run-forward-right run-forward-left has no receiver! are you missing component?

I tried to change animations but still caused this error how to fix it?

[image: this is the error what i'm causing]

Comment: Don't post code, data or error messages as images. Post them as text so that we can copy, paste and search on them. See [ask]

Comment: the error message is also clear.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular to be fair the error is also (somewhat) mentioned in text form by OP here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying "animation event", that's a little white carrot triangle thing on the top bar on an animation just under the time stamps, maybe you added one by accident? Or if you knowingly added one it's likely because you didn't add a referenced method in the event itself.

Some on unity forums had your problem before: https://forum.unity.com/threads/player-animationevent-newevent-has-no-receiver-are-you-missing-a-component.307523/

It's a bit outdated by like 7 or 8 years but the general idea is still the same, check the event the error is referencing in the animation the error is referencing. I hope this helps.

Comment: i fixed it animations wasn't good